# connection refused to Geth websocket port

Tags: go-ethereum

I have installed Geth v.1.8.3-unstable on CentOS 7 / 64-bit with go version go1.8.3.

When trying to start geth with

```
$ nohup geth --datadir /home/bchain/Private_Chain/chaindata --mine --nodiscover --nat any --identity private_chain --networkid 1900 --port 30301 --verbosity 5 --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcapi personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug --ipcpath /home/bchain/Private_Chain/get.ipc --ipcapi admin,db,eth,debug,miner,net,shh,txpool,personal,web3 --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins '*' --wsapi personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug --maxpeers 25 --etherbase 0 --gasprice 0 --targetgaslimit 9999999
```

Geth seems to be running successfully without error messages.

then..

$ `geth attach ws://127.0.0.1:8546`
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial tcp :80: getsockopt: connection refused

$ `geth attach ws://localhost:8546`
Fatal: Unable to attach to remote geth: dial tcp :80: getsockopt: connection refused

I try $ `ncat --listen 127.0.0.1 8546` and $ `ncat 127.0.0.1 8546` and it catches all messages
(I think I have no problem of firewall)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you. This solves my problems and here is for others the working command line:

```
nohup geth --datadir /home/bchain/Private_Chain/chaindata --mine --nodiscover --nat any --identity private_chain --networkid 1900 --port 30301 --verbosity 5 --ipcpath /home/bchain/Private_Chain/geth.ipc --rpc --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --rpcport 8545 --rpccorsdomain '*' --rpcapi personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug --ws --wsaddr 0.0.0.0 --wsport 8546 --wsorigins '*' --wsapi personal,admin,db,eth,net,web3,miner,shh,txpool,debug --maxpeers 25 --etherbase 0 --gasprice 0 --targetgaslimit 9999999
```